# Why Windows Server 2003 causes "varchar to datetime out-of-range", wheras Server 2008 does not

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, datetime, iis-6

I have written a small Asp.net application using Entity Framework.

A Stored Procedure accepts the following:
employeeID int, startDate varchar(12),endDate varchar(12)

I then use SQL server to convert the short date strings to DateTime.

```
SET @correctStartDate = CONVERT(DATETIME,(convert(varchar(10),@startDate,103) + ' 00:00:00am'), 103)
SET @correctEndDate = CONVERT(DATETIME,(convert(varchar(10),@endDate,103) + ' 11:59:59pm'), 103)
```

In development environment iis7 Windows Server 2008 with SQL Server 2008 R2 there are no issues.

If we deploy to production server iis6 (Windows Server 2003 SP2 with SQL Server 2008 R2) we get:

"The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

Why would this be? Both have regional settings the same.

Comment: It is the language settings of the **login** that determine how ambiguous date formats are interpreted. These might be different between servers. You could save yourself a lot of bother by just using appropriate `date` datatypes for your parameters.

Comment: NB: You can run `DBCC USEROPTIONS` on both servers under the same credentials as your application is using to determine the language settings mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you Martin. Your response was really useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was what Martin said. The language settings have a login context.

To solve the issue I have inserted the datetime into the stored procedure instead of the datetime.ToShortDateString() method.

You could also use myDatetime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

Answer (score 0):

What are the values of start and end date?

Try doing the same using datetime2 instead of datetime.